# Splash Screen - Touch to Skip

Tags: java, android, touch

I have the following code:

```
package com.example.top_tech_deals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Splash extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisLoveBacon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(TravisLoveBacon);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);




VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splashvid2;

vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));

vv.start();


    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(12000);

            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent     ("android.intent.action.MENU");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);

            }
        }

    };
    timer.start();
}


//Function that will handle the touch

@Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            synchronized(timer){

                splashTread.notifyAll();

            }

        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

By using one of Bucky's tutorials I managed to create the above code which is used to create a splash screen for 12 seconds. I also modified it so that a Video will play. The main problem I'm having is with the last bit of the code which is the OnTouchEvent I found online. What it should do is allow the user to skip the splash screen simply by tapping the screen, which should take the user to the MENU file.

The error seems to be in this line:

```
synchronized(timer){
```

Which says "error timer cannot be resolved into a variable"

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code:

```
package com.example.top_tech_deals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Splash extends Activity{

Thread timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisLoveBacon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(TravisLoveBacon);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);




VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splashvid2;

vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));

vv.start();


    timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                 synchronized (this) {
        wait(12000);
         }

            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent     ("android.intent.action.MENU");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);

            }
        }

    };
    timer.start();
}


//Function that will handle the touch

@Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            synchronized(timer){

                timer.notify();

            }

        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `timer` variable is local to your `onCreate()` method, but you're trying to access it (via `synchronized`) in a different method -- so it is unresolved. You need to either move `timer` to being a class data member, or use some other object whose scope is available in your `onTouchEvent()` method.

Answer (score 1):

User a count `downTimer` instead of using a thread and in the override method onFinish()

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer =  new CountDownTimer(12000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       //ToDO
     }

     public void onFinish() {
              Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent     ("android.intent.action.MENU");
              startActivity(openStartingPoint);
     }
  }.start();
```

and in onTouch()

```
@Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        startActivity(openStartingPoint);
        countDownTimer.cancle(); 
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your timer variable is not declare at class scope,it is declared in onCreate() function thats why other methods are not able to get it by reference. I suggest declare this as class variable like  this `private Thread timer = null;`  and initialize it in oncreate() method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisLoveBacon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(TravisLoveBacon);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splashvid2;
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
        vv.start();

        this.timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(12000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent     ("android.intent.action.MENU");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
```